# Escape special characters in Javascript SQL Query

Tags: javascript, sql, escaping

I'm trying to send an SQL query with javascript using a variable sourced from an input. In this input, characters like ' and " along with others may be entered.

Here's what my script function looks like:

```
function insertJobDesc (r) {
        rowid=r;
        var qty = document.getElementById('Qty' + r).value;
        var desc = document.getElementById('Desc' + r).value;
        desc = desc.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, '"&quot;"').replace(/'/g, '"&#039;"');

        sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+jobdesc+SET+qty="+qty+",+description='"+desc+"',+rowID="+rowid+"+WHERE+id="+rowid+"+AND+jobID="+jobID);
    }
```

An example of the value for 'desc' that I'd want to send is:
80-0234-1 6'5" GATE
So it's a combination of numbers, letters, and special characters.
I tried to replace each of them but it didn't work out.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is dangerous and dumb. You are exposing db info that would allow anyone to delete your whole table. SQL queries have no business being exposed in browser...compile them at server with the form values sent only and be sure to validate the values sent.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not too concerned about any injection issues as the site is only being used on the local network by a select few.

Comment: Still no reason to do it this way. One person may get disgruntled one day. Doesn't make it any simpler coding query in browser vs on server and you have no way to validate the input this way

Comment: Okay, well that's a secondary issue. For now, I'm after a solution to the posted problem. I appreciate your concern though.

Comment: Use POST and issue dissapears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use encodeURIComponent()

```
function insertJobDesc (r) {
    rowid=r;
    var qty = document.getElementById('Qty' + r).value;
    var desc = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('Desc' + r).value);

    sendAsync("editDatabase.php?sql=UPDATE+jobdesc+SET+qty="+qty+",+description='"+desc+"',+rowID="+rowid+"+WHERE+id="+rowid+"+AND+jobID="+jobID);
}
```

Disclaimer: Don't ever do anything like this...

Comment: Best part of this answer was the disclaimer, so that one's definitely the accepted answer.